# Transfer deeply nested objects between Panels as simply as possible

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection

I'm trying to create a simple Kanban board style app in WPF, using MVVM pattern.

The board has a dynamic amount of columns, each column has a dynamic amount of tasks. Here's how the core structure of it in the *View* looks like.

```
<Window.Content>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TaskColumns}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource taskColumn}"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Style="{StaticResource task}">
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window.Content>
```

The *ViewModel* equivalent of this structure is an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Task>>` to which these elements bind. Their equivalents in *View* are `StackPanel` and `Border`.

I want to transfer a task between two columns using Drag and Drop events (Drag Border -> Drop StackPanel), and that itself is simple, but what I don't know is how to let ViewModel know **which** tasks to transfer and to **which** column. Maybe if possible, do it in *View* and update *ViewModel* accordingly.

I've tried finding indices from the parents to pass them like that: `_viewModel.TransferTask(int sourceTaskIndex, int sourceColumnIndex, int targetColumnIndex)`, but with a structure like this this solution quickly got into an overly complicated mess with `.Parent`, sometimes `.TemplateParent` and `(Panel)` conversions, very confusing to both write and read.

I don't know how to get these indices in any other way either. Getting mouse coordinates with canvas seems like a nuclear option that doesn't seem fix the complexity.

Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: i suggest you to use a MVVM framework which have messaging..so you could share informations between your viewmodels.. (caliburn.micro or others frameworks)

Comment: My knee jerk reaction would be to store the "DraggingObject" (your `Task`) and also capture the "DroppedCollection" (your `ObservableCollection<Task>`). You would probably need to maintain the "DraggedFromCollection" too. I would capture these either in Code behind events, and set them in the ViewModel, or use a Command directly in the ViewModel. Then if everything is successful you can call a `.Remove()` on the original list, and a `.Add()` on the dropped collection within the ViewModel. I dont think you need to get indicies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider to replace the `ItemsControl` with a `ListBox`. `ListBox` is an advanced `ItemsControl` in that it allows scrolling and has performance features like UI virtualization (which is enabled by default).
It would also make very much sense to create a dedicated control e.g. `KanbanBoard` that wraps those columns and implements the drag&drop logic. Just to encapsulate the related logic. It will also help to maintain/extend the features and to reuse the control.

Your design is too complicated and should be changed in order to implement the drag&drop feature more conveniently.

Next step is to simplify your data structure. A Kanban board reflects a workflow whereas each column represents an activity. There is no reason that the data structure already reflects those columns. It should be a simple flat collection of items.
Consider the items to be the "physical" data entities while the columns are just an abstraction or an abstract mapping like an index/state of the data item that is transitioning through the workflow.

So instead of having a data structure that reflects the workflow itself, the simple work item data models must have a state or an index that maps to their current workflow state (column). Now when the work item transitions from workflow state to workflow state according to specific transitioning rules, you only modify the data model's attributes to reflect the new state.
For example, when transitioned into the last column, the state of the work item changes e.g. from "Review" to "Closed". It still remains in the same initial collection.

***The following example code is kind of a pseudo code to give an idea of the class design and class responsibilities.***

This means you separate data from visualization.
The idea is that the client (e.g. a view model class or data models) of the `KanbanBoard` control...

1. binds a collection of work items to the `KanbanBoard.ItemsSource` property of type `IList`. The data type of the collection is unknown to the `KanbanBoard`. This is the data part.
2. defines columns using the API exposed by the `KanbaBoard`. A column is defined by index and name.
   The API could be another `KanbanBoard.ColumnSource` collection property of type `IList`, allowing to bind another e.g. `string` collection. Each `string` represents a column name and the index of the `string` maps to the column's index (optionally, `KanbanBoard` could allow the definition of a `DataTemplate` assigned to a `ColumnTemplate` property that enables the support of any data type for the column definitions). This means rearranging the column source collection will rearrange the columns in the `KanbanBoard` (if the source collection is a `ObservableCollection`).
3. transitions an item by drag&drop. Transitioning changes the column index of the work item.
4. can define a e.g. `WorkflowItem.Index` property (given that the source collection holds a set of `WorkflowItem` data models) that is bound to the item container via a `KanbaBoard.ItemContainerStyle` property. This requires the `KanbaBoard` to introduce a custom item container type `KanbanBoardItem` that could extend `ListBoxItem` and add a `ColumnIndex` property to enable the model binding of `WorkflowIndex`.
   Now when an item transitions, the `KanbanBoard` will adjust the `KanbaBoardItem.ColumnIndex` property accordingly. It's important to always work on the container and not on the data items.
   As a result, to know the position of the work item in the workflow, you would have to read the e.g. `WorkflowItem.Index` property. You can add additional information for example by adding a `State` property etc. to the `KanbaBoardItem` (and data models).

**KanbanBoard.cs**

```
// Pseudo code class
class KanbanBoard : Control
{
  /* Dependenciy properties */
  public IList ItemsSource { get; set; }
  public Style ItemContainerStyle { get; set; }
  public StyleSelector ItemContainerStyleSelector { get; set }
  public DataTemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }
  public IList ColumnSource { get; set; }

  // Style for all columns (target KanbanBoardColumn)
  public Style ColumnStyle { get; set; }

  // StyleSelector to apply individual styling for each column (target KanbanBoardColumn)
  public StyleSelector ColumnStyleSelector { get; set }

  protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    var PART_ColumnHost = (ListBox)GetTemplateChild("PART_ColumnHost");
    PART_ColumnHost.ItemsSource = this.ColumnSource;
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < this.ColumnSource.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
      object columnItem = this.ColumnSource[columnIndex];
      var columnItemContainer = (KanbanBoardColumn)PART_ColumnHost.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(columnItem);
      var columnStyle = this.ColumnStyleSelector?.SelectStyle(columnItem, columnItemContainer)
        ?? this.ColumnStyle;

      // The item container is a KanbanBoardColumn 
      // which is an extended ListBox (see definition below)
      columnItemContainer.Style = columnStyle;
      columnItemContainer.ItemContainerStyle = this.ItemContainerStyle;
      columnItemContainer.ItemContainerStyleSelector = this.ItemContainerStyleSelector;
      columnItemContainer.ItemTemplate = this.ItemTemplate;
      columnItemContainer.ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      
      // Initialize first column with work items
      if (columnIndex == 0)
      {
        columnItemContainer.LoadItems(this.ItemsSource);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**KanbanBoardItem.cs**

```cs
// Pseudo code class
class KanbanBoardItem : ListBoxItem
{
  /* Dependenciy properties */
  public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
  public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Status.cs**

```cs
// Pseudo code class
enum Status
{
  Inactive = 0,
  Open,
  Closed
}
```

Now that the `KanbanBoard` API is defined, we need to design the internals.

1. To display the columns, we can use `ListBox` controls. In order to utilize the custom `KanbanBoardItem` container we need to extend `ListBox` in order to override the `ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride` and `ItemsControl.PrepareContainerForItemOverride` methods. `ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride` simply returns our custom `KanbanBoardItem` which is then used by the extended `ListBox`. The extended `ListBox` for example the `KanbanBoardColumn` is responsible to handle item drop. If an item is dropped it will set the `KanbanBoardItem.Index` property. Because of the additional features like a header it makes sense to modify the default `Style` of the `ListBox` too.
2. We add a `LsitBox´ to the` ControlTemplate`of the`KanbanBoard`. This` ListBox`is used to dynamically create a`KanbanBoardColumn`controls based on the`KanbanBoard.ColumnSource `collection property. The client code can define an optional [`StyleSelector`][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.styleselector?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) in order to customize columns individually (e.g. colorize workflow states).
3. We assign the `KanbanBoard.ItemContainerStyle` to each `KanbanBoardColumn.ItemContainerStyle` property (see `KanbanBorad` class pseudo code above).
4. We assign the `KanbaBoard.ItemTemplate` to each `KanbanBoardColumn.Itemtemplate` property (see `KanbanBorad` class pseudo code above).
5. Drag&drop is implemented in the `KanbanBoardColumn`. It removes the item on drag start and insert it on drop or re-inserts it on drag cancelled. The ´KanbanBoardItem `is the data payload of the drag&drop event data. On drop it also sets the ´KanbanBoardItem.ColumnIndex` to finalize the transition.

**KanbaBoardColumn.cs**

```cs
// Pseudo code class
class KanbanBoardColumn : ListBox
{
  /* Dependenciy properties */
  public object ColumnHeader { get; set; }
  public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
  private ItemsInternal { get; set; }

  public KanbanBoradColumn()
  {
    this.Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    this.ItemsSource = this.ItemsInternal;
  }

  public void LoadItems(IEnumerable newItems)
  {
    this.ItemsInternal = new ObservableCollection<object>(newItems);
    this.ItemsSource = this.ItemsInternal;
  }
 
  protected override void GetContainerForItemOverride()
    => new KanbanBoardItem();
 
  protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
  {
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    if (element is KanbanBoardItem kanbanBoardItem)
    {
      kanbanBoardItem.Index = this.ColumnIndex;
    }
  }

  protected override OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
  {
    var droppedItemContainer = e.Data.GetData(typeof(KanbanBoardItem)) as KanbanBoardItem;
    var item = droppedItemContainer.Content;
    this.ItemsInternal.Add(item);
    var generatedItemContainer = this.ItemContaionerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as KanbanBoardItem;
    generatedItemContainer.ColumnIndex = this.ColumnIndex;
  }

  protected override OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    object clickedItem = GetClickedItem();
    this.ItemsInternal.Remmove(clickedItem);
    var clickedItemContainer = this.ItemContaionerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(clickedItem) as KanbanBoardItem;
   
    // TODO:: Start drag operation and use the clickedItemContainer as payload.
    // If cancelled re-insert the item back into the ItemsInternal collection.
  }   
}
```

**KanbanBoardColumnStyle.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="KanbanBoardColumn">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="KanbanBoradColumn">
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Columnheader}" />
          
          <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**KanbanBoardStyle.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="KanbanBoard">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="KanbanBorad">
        <listBox x:Name="PART_ColumnHost" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

### Usage example

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<WorkItem> WorkItems { get; }
  public ObservableCollection<string> ColumnItems { get; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <KanbanBoard ItemsSource="{Binding WorkItems}"
               ColumnSource="{Binding ColumnItems}">
    <KanbanBoard.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="KanbanBoardItem">

        <!-- Connect item container to item 
             to transfer data like column index -->
        <Setter Property="ColumnIndex" Value="{Binding Index, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </Style>
    </KanbanBoard.ItemContainerStyle>
  </KanbanBoard>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution using `FrameworkElement.Tag` property:**

Adding `Tag="{Binding}"` to each contextual element allows us to search for necessary elements by context and also gives us access to the respective ViewModel objects.

`VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` removes the dilemma of `.Parent` / `.TemplateParent`.

**View:**

```
private void TaskColumn_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var dropedElement = (Border)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Border));

    var task = (Task)dropedElement.Tag;
    var sourceColumn = (ObservableCollection<Task>)FindTaggedParent(dropedElement).Tag;
    var targetColumn = (ObservableCollection<Task>)((StackPanel)sender).Tag;

    _viewModel.TransferTask(task, sourceColumn, targetColumn);
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public void TransferTask(Task task, ObservableCollection<Task> sourceColumn, ObservableCollection<Task> targetColumn)
{
    sourceColumn.Remove(task);
    targetColumn.Add(task);
}
```

Below I've written a method that recursively searches for necessary parents. In this case it looks for all Tags that aren't *null*, however this can be replaced with more specific conditions if necessary.

```
// Throws NullReferenceException on failure.
private FrameworkElement FindTaggedParent(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var parent = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

    if (parent.Tag != null)
    {
        return parent;
    }
    return FindTaggedParent(parent);
}
```